# Answering users with a space sign in their name

Tags: discussion, comments, display-names, comment-replies

When I write comments to users with a name that does not contain a space I can type:

```
@Part
```

And then I would be offered to complete the whole name.  For example if I answer `Martin`, I can just type:

```
@Mart
```

However, if the user name contains spaces like `Martin The Great` this wont work, and the system will swallow my `@Martin The Great` in the comment body.

Does anyone know how to overcome this little annoyance?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: The autocompleter deals with whitespace just fine (removes whitespace but that's not an issue). Are you sure you have an actual problem?

Comment: @Mat, yes, I am. Because here I can do `at Mat` (sorry for the pun) but I don`t know how to answer this guy for example http://stackoverflow.com/users/185657/josh-k, I tried `@Josh K` or `@Josh-K` both would be cut off

Comment: `@JoshK` (that the autocompleter provides) works just fine. It's being removed because you don't need it since Josh is the owner of the post and thus will always be notified.

Comment: @Mat, when you say provides: where do you mean it provided? About the ownership, I understand it, and it makes sense.

Comment: I just meant that the autocompleter autocompletes `@J` to `@JoshK`, which works for notifying him.

Comment: To clarify - is the annoyance that you can't use the full name with spaces for notification (even if the user is notified)? If you read the details of the link I posted in my first comment, you will see that if the spaces (or dashes) are removed, the user is still notified.

Comment: @Oded well, in theory, if the comment replies will support something like `@"John Doe"` then it will indeed be somewhat more friendly to the user and more similar to Facebook format. Just saying. :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, we should all try to be more like facebook, and then everything will be right in the world.